# How to download a specific audio segment from youtube from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube

So I know how to download full you tube video's MP3 files from python, however I just want to be able download a small segment of the video's audio of any inputted start and end times without having to download the full video and removing the unwanted parts afterwards.

Does any one know how to do this?

Comment: https://ytcropper.com/

Comment: download full then use pydub